# Issues with .pop and empty list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

When I put my code into into a loop, and I run it a second time, it says there is nothing in the list. Is there anyway I can reset what is in that list so that when the code runs again, the list has all of its contents again? I've checked other questions but their solutions don't seem to work.

```
global questions
questions = [class_question, color_question, life_question, vacation_question, patronus_question, skills_question, friends_question, values_question, pet_question]

def nextpart():
    user_interface()
    (questions.pop(0))()
    turtle.onscreenclick(shapedrawer)
    turtle.listen()


def quiz_loop():
    reply = raw_input("Do you want to take a quiz? Type Y for yes or N for no, lowercase.")
    while reply == "y": 
        beginning()
        nextpart()
        print ("")
        reply = raw_input("Unsatisfied with the house you got? \n Type Y to retake the quiz or N to end this program. \n Make sure that you use lowercase letters.")
        if reply == "n":
            print ("Okay, bye! Thanks for playing.")
    else:
        print ("I hope you enjoyed your experience.")
```

Comment: Is `nextpart` being set as a callback from the `turtle` module in some of the code you haven't shown? It's not clear whether the `while` loop in `quiz_loop` is supposed to be iterating over the questions, or if it just calls `nextpart` to kick off another loop that isn't as obvious. In any case, I'd guess that using the iteration protocol (either with a `for` loop or with manual calls to `iter` and `next`) may be a better approach than destroying your list with `pop`. I'm not really sure how to turn that suggestion into an answer though, since I don't understand your code very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply moving your questions variable should fix it.

```
def nextpart():
    user_interface()
    (questions.pop(0))()
    turtle.onscreenclick(shapedrawer)
    turtle.listen()


def quiz_loop():
    reply = raw_input("Do you want to take a quiz? Type Y for yes or N for no, lowercase.")
    while reply == "y":
        questions = [class_question, color_question, life_question, vacation_question, patronus_question, skills_question, friends_question, values_question, pet_question]
        beginning()
        nextpart()
        print ("")
        reply = raw_input("Unsatisfied with the house you got? \n Type Y to retake the quiz or N to end this program. \n Make sure that you use lowercase letters.")
        if reply == "n":
            print ("Okay, bye! Thanks for playing.")
    else:
        print ("I hope you enjoyed your experience.")
```

Comment: Also, consider using the str.lower() method so the user can type "Y" or "y":
    While reply.lower() == "y"

Comment: This doesn't work, as `nextpart` can't see the `questions` variable that's a local within `quiz_loop`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new copy of your list for each instance.

```
import copy    
global questions
questions = [class_question, color_question, life_question, vacation_question, patronus_question, skills_question, friends_question, values_question, pet_question]

def nextpart():
    localList = copy.copy(questions) #copy.copy will create a copy of the list
    user_interface()
    (localList.pop(0))()
    turtle.onscreenclick(shapedrawer)
    turtle.listen()
```

Answer (score 0):

**My suggestion: rewrite by all() and map()**

```
questions = [1, 2, 3]

def ask(x):
    print(x)
    reply = input()

    if reply == 'n':
        print("Okay, bye! Thanks for playing.")
        return False

    return True

def loop():
    if all(map(ask, questions)):
        print ("I hope you enjoyed your experience.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop()
```

**demo1**

```
1
y
2
y
3
y
I hope you enjoyed your experience.
```

**demo2**

```
1
y
2
n
Okay, bye! Thanks for playing.
```